# Как вызывать БД с помощью клавиши

Tags: php, javascript

Ну суть вопроса в том что нужно вызвать информацию с бд по нажатию клавиши ! В первою половину экрана на странице! Всем заранее спсибо

Comment: Куда и как его вставлять?

Comment: Да вы правы =) Ну вот есть Таблица Бакуган, там у нас картинка и сам код этого юнита нужно при нажатии клавиши вызвать бакугана который есть у меня и тот что в базе как бота! Как это делать?)))

Comment: Раз делаешь игру, скайп -  <b>alexwindhope</b>, если хочешь добавляйся, по свободе буду помагать...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

test.php:

```
$sql = "select * from `table` where `keypressed`=".$_POST['key'];
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
  print(implode('|',$row));
}
```

js:

```
$('body').keypress(function(e){
  $.post('test.php',{'key':e.which},function(data){
    $("#specialDiv").append(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Хей))) Спасибо))) Ша проверю работает ли!

Comment: Чёто не пашит((

Comment: Зависит от того, что и где вы хотите вызвать. Здесь представлено направление деятельности: при нажатии на клавишу, див с айдишником specialDiv меняет свое содержимое на склеенное содержимое таблицы тэйбл.

Comment: 'key':e.which - двоеточие вместо равно. Косяк, да.  
То что вы делаете игру, тут уже все поняли. =) Точнее, то что мы ее делаем. ^^  
Вопрос: из какой таблицы какие данные нужны?

Comment: Предлагаю перед созданием игры разобраться-таки поплотнее с основами php, mysql и javascript. Тогда вы и сами сможете написать работающую функцию showYourAndOpponentsBakuganOfFirstHalfOfScreen();

Comment: эм.. а jquery у нас теперь во все браузеры по умолчанию прошито? ) было бы странно если оно работало.