# Запрос к MySQL по нажатии кнопки

Tags: javascript, mysql

Народ, подскажите, плизз, как сделать js кнопку, при нажатии которая бы делала мускул запрос (инъекцию и т.д.). Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Как вызывать БД с помощью клавиши?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/32039/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B4-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#32042)

Только Event - click, а не keypress